# How to calculate CRC32 with the rules of polynomial division (XOR division into a column)

Tags: c, crc, crc32

In polynomial division algorithms, zeros are written to the end of the register to calculate various CRCs. The number of these zeros is equal to the degree of the divisor polynomial. However, in the CRC32C method, it includes the active RefIn and RefOut flags, which changes the calculation algorithm. I tried to divide some value into a column and compare it with an online CRC calculator, but I can't get a similar result in any way. Can you use some example of input data to show a CRC32C calculation with column division?

You can also use the bit shift method to check the results:

```
unsigned int CRC_32C(int symnum, char* maintext) {

    unsigned int crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < symnum; i++) {
        unsigned int byte = maintext[i];
        crc ^= byte;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ ((crc & 1) ? 0x82F63B78 : 0);
        };
    }
    crc ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `byte = maintext[i];` --> `byte = (unsigned char) maintext[i];`

Comment: The code as is, _without_ the cast suggested by @ReinstateMonica will give the wrong answer if any of the bytes are > 127. Or you could pass it as `unsigned char* maintext`.

Comment: Also it should be `unsigned synnum`, to avoid a comparsion of signed to unsigned, or `i` should be declared `int`. Better still would be to make `symnum` and `i` both `size_t`.

Comment: Lastly, this assumes that `int` is 32 bits, which is not assured by C. An `int` could be 16 bits, in which case this wouldn't work. Use `uint32_t` for `crc` and the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constant `0x82F63B78` is the reflection of the coefficients of the polynomial below x<sup>32</sup>, so it represents:
x<sup>32</sup> + x<sup>28</sup> + x<sup>27</sup> + x<sup>26</sup> + x<sup>25</sup> + x<sup>23</sup> + x<sup>22</sup> + x<sup>20</sup> + x<sup>19</sup> + x<sup>18</sup> + x<sup>14</sup> + x<sup>13</sup> + x<sup>11</sup> + x<sup>10</sup> + x<sup>9</sup> + x<sup>8</sup> + x<sup>6</sup> + 1.

You can enter that polynomial as `100011110110111000110111101000001` on [this CRC calculator website](https://rndtool.info/CRC-step-by-step-calculator/) to see the division done step-by-step.

To show just the division, we want to replicate what the for loops do. We will remove the pre and post processing in your routine, initializing `crc` to zero, and not doing an exclusive-or at the end. Then the CRC in your question calculated on the ASCII letter "k" gives `0xf84f3859`. Let's run that through the division. Set the data on that web page to the "k", `0x6b`, reflected, which is `11010110`. The result is:

[image]

Now we reflect the resulting remainder `10011010000111001111001000011111` to get `0xf84f3859`. Voilà.

You can also do the division with an initial value of all ones (`0xffffffff`) instead of all zeros. To do that, you invert the first 32 bits of the 40-bit dividend. Then:

```
1101011000000000000000000000000000000000
```

becomes

```
0010100111111111111111111111111100000000
```

Do the division (this is with my own code, whose output isn't as pretty as the web site):

```
10100111111111111111111111111100000000
100011110110111000110111101000001
--------------------------------------
  101000100100011100100001011100100000
  100011110110111000110111101000001
  ------------------------------------
    1011010010100100010110110100101000
    100011110110111000110111101000001
    ----------------------------------
      11101111001010011011001110101010

quotient: 101010
remainder: 11101111001010011011001110101010
```

Take that remainder, reflect it, and invert it (the final exclusive-or), and you get `0xaa326b08`.

Comment: Doesn't the CRC32C calculation algorithm invert all the bits of the incoming message? In the calculator, for the symbol "k" using the CRC32C method, it turned out 0xAA326B08.

Comment: And at the output, all the bits are also inverted. I use this calculator to check: https://crccalc.com/

Comment: Please read my answer, all of it this time. You didn't do what I said. Initialize with zero (_not_ `0xffffffff`), and remove the final exclusive-or.

Comment: I just can't understand why we initialize CRC32C with zero and don't do XOR with 0xffffffff at the end, if that's what it says in the CRC32C standard? Shouldn't the value of division by a polynomial in a column and the value resulting from shifts be the same? The program written above gives the same result as the online calculator.

Comment: I am showing you exactly how the polynomial division matches your `for` loop, which is _in between_ the initialization and final exclusive-or. That initialization and final exclusive-or are trivial and irrelevant to the core of _how to calculate that CRC using the rules of polynomial division_, which is exactly your question.

Comment: So, to get the correct answer, it is enough to simply perform the XOR operation initially and also at the end?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: One last question. How do we get another crc-32c value after adding the next symbol? For example, "b". I mean that we have string " kb" at the very beginning. We just have to do the same algorithm we did with letter "k", but the first XOR after calculating crc-32c for "k" will be different?

Comment: To do it using long division, you need to start with "kb", reflect the bytes individually, append 32 zeros, and then invert the high 32 bits to get the dividend. So `001010011011100111111111111111110000000000000000`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Very lucidly explained.  Now it has become clear how to calculate this type of CRC.  By the way, do you know why when we add the crc-32c value to the end of the file and calculate the new crc value, it is not equal to zero?  It's a property of the cyclic nature of the algorithm.

Comment: If you append the CRC bytes to the message in the correct order, then the CRC of the message + CRC will always be the same _constant_, where that constant is not necessarily zero. For this CRC, the bytes need to be appended in little-endian order, in which case the constant is `0x48674bc7`.